# GAE, oauth2, and admin users

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I currently use the "Google Accounts API" to allow users to login to my GAE app.  So I use `users.create_login_url` and `users.get_current_user` and add an `ndb.UserProperty` to my own user entity so that I can retrieve data for that user.

I'm now in the process of switching to oauth2 (using authomatic).

I don't know how to handle admin users after the switch to oauth2.  I currently use `users.is_current_user_admin` to detect an admin user, but that won't work if the admin logs in with oauth2.

I see two awkward solutions:

1. Keep using the Google Accounts API for admin users and have regular users login with oauth2.
2. Store a list of oauth2 credentials for admin users (hardwired in the code or in the datastore) so admin users will be recognized after login with oauth2.

Is there a better way or should I use one of the above, and if so, which one?

Comment: @konqi, I have answered both questions. Please read both and let me know if you think this is a duplicative question

Comment: @Kekito They looked pretty similar and were created within 9 minutes of each other. That did look like a mistake or spamming but i stand corrected. I'll remove the duplicat comment.

Comment: Oh also I've used awkward solution #2 but with datastore. Yes you'd have to allow a user through hardcoding during setup (or you could do it with the Datastore API) but you could remove that once your users are setup. Lock the door, throw away the key :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll describe how I ended up doing it in case it is helpful for others.

Below is my `Login` handler. If a user goes to "/login" then it displays login buttons.  When a user clicks on a button, the page redirects to, e.g., "/login/google" to do OAuth2 processing.

If I want to login as admin, then I manually enter this URL "/login/gae".

```
class Login(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, provider=None):

        # Show the login page and allow the user to select a provider
        if not provider:
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("login.html")
            self.response.write(template.render())

        # Only for admin login.  Use app engine login.
        elif provider == "gae":
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url("/"))

        # The user has selected a provider so we do oauth2 login.
        else:
            session = Webapp2Session(self, session=self.session)        
            result = authomatic.login(Webapp2Adapter(self),
                                      provider,
                                      session=session,
                                      session_saver=session.save)
            ...
```

To allow admin to logout, I conditionally put an admin logout on my web pages by creating this template variable:

```
logout_url = users.create_logout_url("/") if users.is_current_user_admin() else None
```

and adding this to my page template:

```
{% if logout_url %}
<li><a href="{{ logout_url }}">Admin Logout</a></li>
{% endif %}
```